# What can I assume about pthread_create and file descriptors?

Tags: linux, pthreads, posix, file-descriptor

I just debugged a program that did roughly:

```
pthread_create(...);
close(0);
int t = open("/named_pipe");
assert(t == 0);
```

Occasionally it fails, as `pthread_create` actually briefly opens file descriptors on the new thread – specifically `/sys/devices/system/cpu/online` – which if you're unlucky occur between the `close` and `open` above, making `t` something other than 0.

What's the safest way to do this? What if anything is guaranteed about `pthread_create` regarding file descriptors? Am I guaranteed that if there are 3 file descriptors open before I call pthread_create, then there'll also be 3 open when it's returned and control has been passed to my function on the new thread?

Comment: What fails? [open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/open.html) returns non-negative in case of success, so `assert(t==0)`, should be `assert(t>=0)`. If there are 3 open file descriptor, the next one can be ANY non-negative number not equal to these three. It is OS dependent what `open` returns, you can't make assumption that if 3 descriptors are open it is going to return `4`, and that if you `close(0)` than it's going to return `0`. It returns non-negative number.

Comment: Could you please post the contents of your thread start routine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In multi-threaded programs, you need to use [`dup2` or `dup3`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) to replace file descriptors.  The old trick with immediate reuse after `close` no longer works because other threads and create file descriptors at any time.  Such file descriptors can even be created (and closed) implicitly by glibc because many kernel interfaces use file descriptors.

`dup2` is the standard interface.  Linux also has `dup3`, with which you can atomically create the file descriptor with the `O_CLOEXEC` flag set.  Otherwise, there would still be a race condition, and the descriptor could leak to a subprocess if the process ever forks and executes a new program.

Comment: Thanks, this didn't occur to me immediately as my spawned function itself did not open fds, it was glibc itself doing it briefly on the new thread, before actually invoking my spawned function